# AWS - Dedicated Host EC2 MAC1 family Reservation Pricing ( No Upfront , Partial Upfront and All Upfront ) calculator link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

can anyone tell where can I find the EC2 dedicated-hosts reservation pricing ( No Upfront , Partial Upfront and All Upfront ) with Standard 1 - Year Term and Standard 3-Year Term for  **MAC1** family , I was not able to find it at

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/pricing/#reservations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Amazon EC2 Mac instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-mac-instances.html):

> Mac instances are available only as On-Demand Instances. They are not
> available as Spot Instances or Reserved Instances. You can save money
> on Mac instances by purchasing a Savings Plan.

Also good to know: Mac Dedicated Hosts have a minimum host allocation of 24 hours, this is because of the Apple licensing terms.